# Highlighting tabs in ace

Tags: javascript, regex, tabs, highlighting, ace-editor

I want to be able to highlight(or style) the tabs in ace.

I currently have this regex which does highlight the last tab or spaces; but I want it to highlight all tabs and no spaces.

[image]

[image]

But. The code below doesn't highlight any tabs at all.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
I have added images to show what the output looks like.

Comment: are you sure it doesn't highlight? it creates "errorHighlight" token in https://ace.c9.io/tool/mode_creator.html

Comment: Hello. I am testing it in a html+javascript file. I haven't tried using the mode creator yet. The tabs aren't being highlighted in the browser when I try?

Comment: maybe there are no tabs because of soft tab feature being enabled? try `[ ]` in the regex to check

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve the issue by disabling softtabs with the code: 'editor.session.setUseSoftTabs(false);'   This code detects new tabs entered in the editor .But it doesn't detect tabs that were entered in by another text editor? Example: Edit file.txt in sublimetext and add tabs save it. Open the file in kitchen-sink.html and the tabs are not highlighted.

Comment: sublime has softabs too, if you can select in the middle of the tab, then it is not a tab

Comment: Ahhh right! Are softtabs just another way to turn a tab into multiple spaces instead?

Comment: yes, they are the way